# how to show show active and inactive month from given date array

Tags: php, function, date, compare

I need a `php` function that show active and inactive month.

My array:

```
$dates = array('2014-08','2014-09','2014-11','2014-12','2015-02',)
```

expected output:

```
2014-08 Active   
2014-09 Active    
2014-10 Inactive    
2014-11 Active    
2014-12 Active    
2015-01 Inactive    
2015-02  Active
```

Comment: what is the condition for active or inactive?

Comment: active / inacrtive on which bases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $dates = array('2014-08', '2014-09', '2014-11', '2014-12', '2015-02');
    $begin = new DateTime($dates[0]);
    $end = new DateTime(end($dates) . "+1 month");
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

    foreach($daterange as $date)
        echo $date->format("Y-m") . (in_array($date->format("Y-m") , $dates) ? " active" : " inactive") . "<br />"; 


?>
```

Output:

```
2014-08 active
2014-09 active
2014-10 inactive
2014-11 active
2014-12 active
2015-01 inactive
2015-02 active
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: [REFERENCE](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)

```
<?php
 $dates = array('2014-08', '2014-09', '2014-11', '2014-12', '2015-02');
 $begin = new DateTime( '2014-08' );
 $end = new DateTime( '2015-02' );
 $end = $end->modify( '+1month' ); 

 $interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
 $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

 foreach($daterange as $date){
  if(in_array($date->format("Y-m") , $dates)){
 echo $date->format("Y-m") . "Active"."<br>";
 }else{
 echo $date->format("Y-m") . "Inactive"."<br>";
 }
 }?>
```

Comment: How can it be that all your output is inactive but in OP's expected output he has only 2 inactive ?!

Comment: @Rizier123 yes you are correct but he didn't mention whats the condition behind active/inactive so i put the condition for todays date(Y-m\).

Comment: Look at the question and you will see the condition!

Comment: @Rizier123 got the condition,thankz dear.i'll update the answer sortly

Answer (score 0):

i find this solution worked

reference https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c1dc49c23ddc0813a156/42dc128b9cfaf04675c5fd8c6d267b6c507f34cf